# iOS 7: How to get own number via private API?

Tags: ios7, phone-number, core-telephony

Old ways don't work any more:

// way 1

```objc
void *lib = dlopen("/Symbols/System/Library/Framework/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony", RTLD_LAZY);
NSString* (*getPhoneNumber)() = dlsym(lib, "CTSettingCopyMyPhoneNumber");

if (getPhoneNumber == nil) {
    NSLog(@"getPhoneNumber is nil");
    return nil;
}
NSString* ownPhoneNumber = getPhoneNumber();
```

// way 2

```objc
extern NSString* CTSettingCopyMyPhoneNumber();
NSString *phone = CTSettingCopyMyPhoneNumber();
```

Related questions:

[Is it possible to detect a phone number of the device in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13460804/is-it-possible-to-detect-a-phone-number-of-the-device-in-ios)

**[UPDATE]**

**Provided method works on iOS 6.1.4 without JB and iOS 7.1.2 with JB**

Thanks to user [creker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2363866/creker) for hint!

To get number you have to use following way:

**1.** Code

```objc
-(NSString*) getMyNumber {
    NSLog(@"Open CoreTelephony");
    void *lib = dlopen("/Symbols/System/Library/Framework/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony",RTLD_LAZY);
    NSLog(@"Get CTSettingCopyMyPhoneNumber from CoreTelephony");
    NSString* (*pCTSettingCopyMyPhoneNumber)() = dlsym(lib, "CTSettingCopyMyPhoneNumber");
    NSLog(@"Get CTSettingCopyMyPhoneNumber from CoreTelephony");

    if (pCTSettingCopyMyPhoneNumber == nil) {
        NSLog(@"pCTSettingCopyMyPhoneNumber is nil");
        return nil;
    }
    NSString* ownPhoneNumber = pCTSettingCopyMyPhoneNumber();
    dlclose(lib);
    return ownPhoneNumber;
}
```

**2.** Build application without signing:
[image]

**3.** Create xml file (entitlements.xml) with following content:

```objc
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>com.apple.coretelephony.Calls.allow</key>
        <true/>
        <key>com.apple.coretelephony.Identity.get</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

Where:

**com.apple.coretelephony.Calls.allow** — for calls

**com.apple.coretelephony.Identity.get** — for getting own number

**4.** Sing app with entitlements.xml
Copy files in one folder:

```objc
./FolderForRunSinging/
    YourApp.app
    entitlements.xml
```

**entitlements.xml** - created xml

**YourApp.app** - binaries for your app copied from XCode files
To find where your binaries you can use command:

```objc
$ls -la ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ | grep YourApp
```

Path should be like this:

```objc
/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/YourApp-cktasembftvbmqaaiiunvljdwocs/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/YourApp.app
```

Run singing command:

```objc
$codesign --sign='iPhone Developer: FirstName  SecondName (XXXXXXXX)’
--entitlements entitlements.xml YourApp.app
```

'iPhone Developer: FirstName  SecondName (XXXXXXXX)' - name of your certificate in keychain

[image]

**5.** Copy application **YourApp.app**  on your device using ssh to folder

```objc
/Applications
```

**6.** Restart springboard (run on device):

```objc
$su mobile -c uicache 1>/dev/null 2>&1
```

Working sample could be found on [github](https://github.com/0x8BADFOOD/iOS7-makecall-sample)

Result on iOS 7.1.2 (**JB is required!**):

[image]

Result on iOS 6.1.3 (**works without JB and without special signature just build and run**)

[image]

Comment: The sample is not working in iOS 8.4. Does it need any additional works to make it work in xcode 6.4 ?

Comment: This is a useful answer, but the **answer** should be split out from the question, as a true answer below. Nothing wrong with answering your own question. Even accepting it :)

Answer (score 9):

In order to use this API you need to sign your app with entitlement `com.apple.coretelephony.Identity.get` with boolean value set to true.

Comment: how to sign entitlement.can you please share any link to  get mobile number.

Comment: FYI, just in case someone else is interested to use this private API entitlement in an enterprise app, furgeddaboutit. You can create an entitlements plist and add that to the project, but you cannot add com.apple.coretelephony.Identity.get to the provisioning profile (you cannot add custom entitlements to the profile), so the app will build but will tank when trying to run on ios.

Comment: I understand that we could not add this to the provisioning profile, and so it is not possible to get the user active/current phone number. Thank you Apple, again iOS developers have another challenge against android developers :)