# What are the possible ways of getting iPhone phone number to use in my application without jailbreak?

Tags: ios, iphone, phone-number, core-telephony

I want to get my own phone number to use it in my application. But there is no native iPhone application development API to get it.

Is there any other way to get it. Please Help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatically get own phone number in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/193182/programmatically-get-own-phone-number-in-ios)

Comment: In case of iOS 7 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19504478/ios-7-how-to-get-own-number-via-private-api/20830611#20830611

Comment: Thanks for your response. But is there any more possible ways to get it. please help if there is any. Thanks

Comment: On iOS 7 you cannot do it without JB but on iOS 6 you can.

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19504478/ios-7-how-to-get-own-number-via-private-api][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19504478/ios-7-how-to-get-own-number-via-private-api