# How to get phone number in cordova ionic(android ,ios)?

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

I want to get phone number in an application that use ionic and cordova.I've been search some plugins to do that but finally i doesn't find something relevant or something to work.Does anyone have an idea about a working plugin?
Thanks to all!

Comment: You mean that you want to get the phone number of the device that your application is running on?

Comment: Yes..that kind of application

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cordova / Phonegap get phone number of device (Android & iOS)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32005570/cordova-phonegap-get-phone-number-of-device-android-ios)

Comment: I've found a plugin that use that tehnique...but doesn't works...I've found somewhere an article that says in not compatible with Android versions 6.0.x

Comment: Please add that to your question.  Put as much information as you can to express why this is not a duplicate.  Link the article and put the relevant information that states why it is incompatible into your question as a quote.  Do you get any particular error messages whenever you try to run the plugin?